# Standardizing Variable for a Regression of X on ratio Y/Z: What would you do?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, standardization

I have a 3 variables X,Y,Z and I'd like to observe the effect of X on Y/Z.

(If you're interested in the flavor text of this question: X is the capacity of air conditioners (BTU), Y is the price, and Z is the energy efficiency ratio (EER). I want to observe the cost of energy efficiency as the size of air conditioner increases.)

X and Y are denoted in the thousands, while Z is denoted as a range from 3 to 3.5.
Question 1, would you standardize the variables? What would be the standard practice for this?

Question 2, after the standardization, the results are a little weird. Why are they weird - is it because the division of Y and Z that mess up the signs?

Question 3, I made a dirty fix by adding all variable by 3 to move everything 3 standard deviation upwards. What would you do, are there a better way to do this?

Question 4, hypothetically if there is a strong correlation between X and Y, but not Z. Will the relationship skew the result? If so, is there a way to mitigate this?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest visual inspection of scatterplots of XY, XZ and YZ to see if the is any obvious data transformation that might help. Also, visual inspection of 3D scatterplot of X, Y and Z might be instructive to see the shape of the data (flat pr curved surface). What is your preferred programming language or statistics tool?

Comment: Could you explain what "little weird" means?  When you do, please describe your model.  Apparently it is not an ordinary least squares regression, for otherwise the issue of standardization would not even arise.

Comment: I prefer SPSS, but scikit-learn Python code is also okay.

As for "little weird", the beta is positive when the data is non-standardize and when it is standardized but push 3 standard deviation upwards. However, beta is negative when a model is run just after standardizing data. The model is just simple ols regression with enter method. (SPSS, Analyze -> Regression -> Linear)
Thanks!